# Using Spock to test Spring JdbcTemplate

Tags: unit-testing, java-8, spock, jdbctemplate

I have the following Java 8 DAO method that uses Spring JdbcTemplate to hit a database:

```
class MyAppDao {
    @Inject
    DataSource dataSource

    public List<String> getFizzByBuzzIds(List<Integer> buzzIds) {
        String sql = "SELECT * from buzzes WHERE buzz_id IN ( :buzzIds )";

        NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        Map<String, Object> paramValues = new HashMap<>(1);
        paramValues.put("buzzIds", buzzIds);

        List<Buzz> buzzes = jdbcTemplate.query(sql,
            paramValues, (rs, rowNum) -> {
                return new Buzz(rs.getString("buzz_id"), rs.getString("buzz_key"),
                rs.getString("buzz_external_id"));
            }
        );

        List<String> fizzes = figureOutSomehow();

        return fizzes;
    }
}
```

I **cannot** change the dependencies injected into this method. The `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` instance *must* be defined inside this method. The only thing I can mock (easily) is the `dataSource`.

I am *trying* (and I **know**, the method isn't written to be conducive to unit tests at all!) to write a Spock unit test for this, and just want to verify that when `getFizzByBuzzIds` is called, that `jdbcTemplate.query` is called (with *any* arguments).

My best attempt:

```
def 'getFizzByBuzzIds attempts to get case info from the DB'() {
    given:
    MyAppDao dao = Spy(MyAppDao, constructorArgs: [ dataSource ]) {
        getJdbcTemplate() >> Mock(JdbcTemplate) {
            1 * query('', null)   // ???
        }
    }

    when:
    List<Integer> buzzIds = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    dao.getFizzByBuzzIds(buzzIds)

    then:
    1 * dao.jdbcTemplate.query('', null)    // ???
}
```

How can I configure the `Spy` and the `then` block label so that executing `getFizzByBuzzIds` verifies whether the underlying `JdbcTemplate.query(...)` method is called?

Comment: a `JdbcTemplate` is a class, it's not easy to mock it. Moreover, it's not easy too to mock a `DataSource` (because of all the other classes like Connection and PreparedStatement). However, it's easy to use an in-memory database to test this kind of methods, like H2 or HSQLDB

Comment: The MockRunner project (http://mockrunner.github.io/) provides a good mock DataSource implementation - http://mockrunner.github.io/mockrunner/mockrunner-jdbc/apidocs/index.html